# Как ограничить скорость падения rigitbody unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хочется, чтобы на тело действовала физика падения(гравитация), но скорость падения была ограниченна. Думаю это можно как-то аккуратно сделать через трение, но не знаю как оно точно работает. Из школьной физики знаю, что сила трения о воздух может быть как линейно зависима от скорости падения, так и квадратично. В общем хочется увидеть конкретную реализацию ограничения скорости.

PS костыль `if(abs(rv.velocity.y) > max_vel) rb.velocity.y = max_vel` не подойдёт. Из-за такого вмешательства в физику тело при падении начинает немного дёргать, и это неуместно в моей задаче.

Answer (score 1):

Там, где вы считаете изменение скорости за счёт гравитации

```
Vy = Vy - g * dt
```

добавьте противодействие силы сопротивления воздуха

```
Vy = Vy - g * dt - Sign(Vy) * k * ro * S * Vy * Vy / 2
```

`Sign` - функция знака аргумента (`-1;0;1` для отрицательных, нуля, положительных, `Math.Sign` в шарпе)
`k` - некий коэффициент (для достоверности можно подобрать его таким, что установившая скорость падения тела массой 100 кг и площадью 0.25 м^2 составит 50 м/c)
`ro` - плотность воздуха
`S` - площадь поперечного сечения тела

Зачем `Sign`? - чтобы учесть, что сила сопротивления всегда действует против направления движения.

Answer (score 1):

У `Rigidbody` есть настройка `Drag`. Чем больше значение, тем меньше скорость.

Второй вариант - попробуй засунуть в `FixedUpdate()`

```
rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(rigidbody.velocity, maxVelocity);
//но лучше воспользуйся первым вариантом.
```

Так же там же есть `gravity Scale` который позволяет не менять настройки физики всей сцены

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а здесь можно почитать больше про прыжки: [https://gamedevbeginner.com/how-to-jump-in-unity-with-or-without-physics/#:~:text=One%20simple%20method%20of%20creating,of%20gravity%20on%20a%20Rigidbody](https://gamedevbeginner.com/how-to-jump-in-unity-with-or-without-physics/#:%7E:text=One%20simple%20method%20of%20creating,of%20gravity%20on%20a%20Rigidbody).

Answer (score 1):

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]

public class Foo : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [SerializeField] float _maxFallSpeed = -10;
    private Rigidbody _rigidbody;
    
    private void Awake () 
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<>(Rigidbody);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate () 
    {
        if (_rigidbody.velocity.y < _maxFallSpeed)
            _rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(rigidbody.velocity.x, _maxFallSpeed, rigidbody.velocity.z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть вот такой [метод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1305780/555302).

Но он, правда, ограничивает скорость объекта во всех направлениях, может вам подойдет.

> Проверить достигает ли твоя скорость предела. Это то что указывается в
> speed твоего Rigidbody. Найти эту скорость можно через
> RigidBody.velocity.magnitude
>
> Соответственно теперь проверять является ли скорость больше
> максимальной? Если да то нормализовать скорость, и умножить на
> максимальную скорость. В таком варианте при любом движении физическая
> скорость не будет выше максимальной
> Текст из ответа по ссылке.

```
    if (_rigidBody.velocity.magnitude >= maxVelocity)
{
   _rigidBody.velocity = _rigidBody.velocity.normalized * maxVelocity;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]